# How do you authenticate with an API key inside an IBM Cloud Function?

Tags: serverless, cloudant

I am writing an IBM Cloud Function which uses the python SDK to interface with a Cloudant service. I have the Cloudant service up, the databases populated, and service credentials / API key ready. However when I try to instantiate the CloudantV1 service inside my Function I get a runtime error "must provide authenticator".

I looked up the error in their git repos and it seems like it is trying to setup an authenticator object by looking up values from environment variables, which do not exist in the Function. I just want to pass my API key directly, but I have not found a method to do this. I am using basic code from the examples so I think my calls are correct.

I have considered injecting the environment variables inside the Function, but that sounds like a major hack. I must be doing something incorrectly. Please help me understand what it is. Here is basic Function python code which reproduces the error:

```
from ibmcloudant.cloudant_v1 import CloudantV1
def main(params_dict):
    service = CloudantV1.new_instance()
    # unreachable
    return { "message" : "hello world" }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an example for programmatic authentication at https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/cloudant?code=python#programmatic-authentication - it basically looks like this:

```py
from ibmcloudant.cloudant_v1 import CloudantV1
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator

authenticator = IAMAuthenticator('yourAPIkey')
service = CloudantV1(authenticator=authenticator)
service.set_service_url('https://yourserviceurl.example')
```

Comment: Thanks so much I don’t know why I couldn’t find that.